# Scala application definition error : not found : value ~

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

[image]

Error message : not found : value ~

Any help ?

#### === EDIT ===

Actual code :

`val rowParser: RowParser[Category] = {
    long("id") ~ str("name") ~ str("description") ~ long("parent_id") map {
      case id ~ name ~ description ~ parent_id =>
        Category(id, name, description, Category(parent_id))
    }
  }`

Imports:

```
package models

import anorm.RowParser
import anorm.SQL
import anorm.SqlParser.long
import anorm.SqlParser.str
import anorm.sqlToSimple
import anorm.toParameterValue
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
```

Comment: Seriously. Taking a screenshot, cropping and uploading it takes more effort than copy and pasting the code.

Comment: Probably it's just to illustrate the red underscores underneath the tildes. :)  I totally agree that it's very inaccessible and at the very least the actual code should be pasted in alongside the screengrab. :)

Comment: You should post the actual code, with the imports for that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `~` class from `anorm` package.

```
import anorm.~
```

This class takes two params:

```
final case class ~[+A, +B](_1: A, _2: B) extends Product with Serializable
```

So it can be used with infix syntax in pattern matching:

A ~ B is same as ~(A, B)

Comment: I use anorm with play, and if i don't import anorm.~ I get exact same error. Guys explain downvote.

Comment: I think the two downvotes are unjust because this answer is clear, reasonable and worthy.

Comment: By the way, it's not necessarily Anorm in this case, it could be Slick, or any other database API. The OP needs to give more details which database API he is using.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks ! I'm new to scala(with eclipse), don't know why eclipse doesn't import code dependencies itself.